Calculating a confidence interval for a sum of events
I have a trial that contains a set of events, and a bunch of times no event occurred. Each event has a certain magnitude, but the magnitudes of the events follows a reasonable distribution (normal).
What I have:

Probability of an even occurring with a 95% confidence interval (event rate) found using a test of proportions
A 95% confidence interval for the magnitude of an event using a t-test across all events

What I want to find

95% confidence interval for the sum of all events in a trial of size n.

An example:
Imagine I am trying to estimate how much a store will make if n customers come in. I have collected data on how likely a customer is to purchase anything, and data on the average amount of any one purchase.
Because the distribution of purchase amounts is extremely non-normal (you have a bunch of customers that don't purchase anything) running a t-test or a z-test across all customers would violate the normality assumption. To add to the problem the shop is small so the number of purchases made is small (~10) and the number of customers is larger, but still not huge (~50).
Is there anyway to get a 95% confidence interval for the revenue generated if n customers come in?
UPDATE:
Update with MATLAB code.
I was able to run some simulations using the following parameters
Probability of purchase 25% STD 0.05
Mean purchase amount 100 STD 10
Customers: 50
Simulating 50,000 times yielded a 95% confidence interval of 12.41 to 38.65 for revenue per customer.

Code:
rng('default') % For reproducibility
numberofTrials = 50000;
trialSize = 50;
means = zeros(1,numberofTrials);
prob = normrnd(.25,0.05,[1,numberofTrials]);

parfor meanindex = 1:numberofTrials
valuepool = normrnd(100,10,[1,trialSize]);
trial = zeros(1,trialSize);
currentValIndex = 1; 
for eventindex = 1:trialSize
    occurance = rand(1);
    if occurance < prob(meanindex)
        trial(eventindex) = valuepool(currentValIndex);
        currentValIndex = currentValIndex + 1;
    end
end
means(meanindex) = mean(trial);
end

means = rot90(means);
%pd = fitdist(means, 'Rayleigh')
%pd = fitdist(means, 'kernel')
%pd = fitdist(means, 'Normal')
%qqplot(means, pd)
hist = histogram(means);
histfit(means, hist.NumBins, 'Normal')
ylabel("Frequency")
xlabel("Mean Purchase Amount")
quantile(means,[.05, .95])


Maybe spit this in half? So you have one CI for someone buying something or not and  one CI for when someone buys something. Also notice that a non-Normal distribution can still have a normally distributed mean. For example, the sample mean of $n$ Poisson-distributed random variables with mean $\lambda$ is approximately normally distributed because of the CLT. The variables themselves are not (they are Poissson) but their mean is Gaussian.

I was thinking about that, but that leaves two separate confidence interval, and I don't really see a way to combine them into a single confidence interval for the total revenue generated. I ran some simulations in MATLAB and will post the results tomorrow once I get things cleaned up.

You could try to bootstrap the confidence intervals. For each $n$ randomly select $n$ customers with replacement from your sample and compute their revenue. Repeat this 1000 times or so and derive the confidence interval from these 1000 hypothetical revenues.
